# CMake: Not Connecting -lrt to project

Tags: cmake

I have a project, dependent on the rt library, that shows undeclared errors for functions ddefined in LIBRT when using make following running the "cmake .". I've looked at the plethora of suggestions for questions similar to this but none worked for me. Using the functions check_include_files() and check_library_exists() return TRUE, and it appears I succeed in finding the library using find_library(). I even get "-lrt" appended at the end of the link.txt file.

Anyways, I am a bit stumped and looking for some guidance. Below is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project (proj_name C)   
enable_language(C)

set (SOURCES
   /source/file/path
)

add_definitions (-std=c99)
add_executable (proj_name ${SOURCES})

find_library(LIBRT rt)
if(LIBRT)
    target_include_directories (proj_name PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} 
        /proj/includes/path #not including rt header path 
        ${RT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )
    target_link_libraries(proj_name PUBLIC ${LIBRT})
endif(LIBRT)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc)

include(CheckIncludeFiles)
check_include_files(mqueue.h HAVE_MQUEUE_H)
if(NOT HAVE_MQUEUE_H)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "mqueue.h not found")
endif(NOT HAVE_MQUEUE_H)

include(CheckLibraryExists)
check_library_exists(rt timer_gettime "" HAVE_RT)
if(NOT HAVE_RT)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "timer_gettime not found")
endif(NOT HAVE_RT)
```

Running on WSL Ubuntu.

Thanks for any insight possible!

Comment: I guess `${RT_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is empty, can you `MESSAGE()` it?

Comment: What functions are undeclared? Have you included the headers?

Comment: `timer_gettime` is available  only if `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L`, see [man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_gettime) and [macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

Comment: You can also make gcc define `_GNU_SOURCE` with just `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: timer functions (timer_create, etc), usleep, mq_timedreceive all implicit definitions and struct itimerspec, sig stuff (struct sigaction, sigemptyset, etc) and timer_t undefined/unknown. Thought including -lrt as a linker flag would include all these since they reside in LIBRT.

Comment: What seems weird is that it isn't saying that mq_open and a few other function are undefined, meaning it can access those definitions but not the others.

Comment: I am 99,99% percent sure you didn't define the macro _POSIX_C_SOURCE in your code. You need that if you want posix functions. mq_open is defined without any macro needed, but posix extended function need the macro definition. See manual page, theres a line right below function definition like from [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html): `Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

       timer_create(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L`. Can you check if the code works with `-std=gnu99` ?

Comment: Ya I can test that. Would that have any effect on building it through a gcc script? Because the project builds fine with the script.

Comment: Switching from -std=c99 to -std=gnu99 allowed it to build 100%. So im assuming that adds the Test Macro you mentioned?

Comment: Read POSIX documentation. There is a [guarding #if](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/time.h#L329) inside time.h that makes the function visible. They are visible ONLY IF _YOU_ (the programmer) wants them to be, not always. You should `#define _POSIX_SOURCE  199309L` on top on each of your C file to make them visible or `-D_POSIX_SOURCE=199309L` switch or use `-std=gnu?` defines `-D_GNU_SOURCE` which makes ALL gnu posix symbols visible.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!